# MySQL query in Inno Setup

Tags: mysql, inno-setup, pascalscript

Before knowing about [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) used [IzPack](http://izpack.org) to do my installer, due to the need to verify if the port of the service that was about to create was in use, towards a query to the database with the driver jdbc, so if the connection was valid then send a error message to change the port.

So this is the way I did before, but I do not know how to do it in Inno Setup:

```java
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conn =
        DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/database", "root", password);

    if (conn.isValid(0)) {
        error = "A server-type installation already exists in: " + server;
        return Status.ERROR;
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you install MySQL on your own? Or do you rely on existing MySQL installation? + Your code does not show any query, nor what you do with results.

Comment: sorry i think that was call a query, my friend told me, but now i kno its a conection, just want to try to replicate the code, but I found an easy way that discover the used port, and thank you so much for you responses.

Comment: Post it as an answer.

Comment: OK, now after you edited your question, my answer does not make sense. And your question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21701847/850848 (as you found yourself) + Though the MySQL query question is useful. So if you do not mind, I'm reverting your question for benefit of others.

Comment: thats good thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to execute a command-line MySQL client (`mysql`).

For some examples of executing an executable and checking its exit code and/or inspecting its output, see:

- [Using Process Exit code to show error message for a specific File in [Run]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9621099/850848);
- [How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136770/850848)

Answer (score 0):

found an easy way to discover port from answer [How to check if port is usable in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701847/how-to-check-if-port-is-usable-in-inno-setup)

```
function CheckPortOccupied(Port:String):Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C netstat -na | findstr'+' /C:":'+Port+' "', '', 0,
       ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  if ResultCode <> 1 then 
  begin
    Log('this port('+Port+') is occupied');
    Result := True; 
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```